# Tuple initialization with member initialization

Tags: c++, initialization, tuples

This is the code:

```
struct ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode *next;
     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
};

std::tuple<int, ListNode*> head{0, &&ListNode(0)};
```

The error annotation:

```
expected ‘}’ before ‘(’ token
```

I just confused what happened here, is the initialization list not able to accept a inside initialization? I read the cppreference.com and C++ primer. They all have no usage sample like this. But, I wonder is it available for me to do something like this:

```
std::tuple<type, class*> n{ type_value, &&class_initialization }
```

rather than

```
std::tuple<type, class*> n{ type_value, class_reference_or_pointer }
```

Comment: You can't take the address of a temporary

Comment: `&&` is the boolean-AND operator, it needs 2 arguments

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks, I think I have misused the rvalue reference here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You should use single `&` to get the address (i.e. `ListNode*`).
2. You can't take the address of a temporary object (i.e. `ListNode(0)`).

You might want:

```
ListNode node(0);
std::tuple<int, ListNode*> head{0, &node};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and could I ask an another question: can I use the rvalue reference here? I mean, I have noticed it is a temporary and want to pass it to the initialization list. Could you please tell me where my misconceptions is?

Comment: @FrankWang Yes it's possible to pass a temporary directly as rvalue, but you're trying to pass the address of the temporary, it's not rvalue.

Comment: Yeah, I just took some test for it, and learned more about pointer and reference. Thanks for your kind answer.